# Postgres using too much CPU

Tags: php, postgresql, server, pgadmin

I've been trying to debug an issue with postgres where there is far too much CPU usage on the server. I figured it might have to do with unoptimized queries and the like, however, I was unable to find any solution there. I tried using different settings for postgres, tweaking around the config. I have finally set my configurations to :

```
max_connections = 1000
shared_buffers = 4GB
effective_cache_size = 12GB
work_mem = 4194kB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_segments = 32
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
checkpoint_timeout - 15 min
random_page_cost = 0.5
seq_page_cost = 0.2
```

The server can easily provide these resources. I still couldn't get the net CPU usage to fall (it hits 40%+ on a single user, 80%+ on 2, and after 3 it begins to crawl.

Finally, I wrote the following function as a test:

```
public function testLoad(){
    define("DBCOFIG", "host=hostname port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=pwd");
    pg_connect(DBCOFIG)or die('Failed');
    pg_query("select 1");
    echo 'hi';die;
}
```

When I hit this function, it produces the exact same results, i.e. 40% CPU usage while the call is active. Clearly, the issue is not with the queries being fired, but rather the connection itself which php is making to the database. Every user will create a new http request, and every new request will create a new connection to the database, which will then create a problem.

I plan on having a userbase with around 100 parallel connections at any time, so obviously the current setup will not work for me. Any advice on where I'm going wrong? Some configuration I may be missing?

Comment: reuse connections, eg with pgbouncer...

Comment: Yes, you need a connection pool. `max_connections` is way too high. Try to identify what uses the CPU. Profile with `perf` or `oprofile`.